# Are there any recommendations for integrating Lucene.NET into an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lucene.net

I'm wondering if there are any recommendations, best practises or top-tips for integrating a Lucene.NET based search into an ASP.NET MVC web application?

Things I've read (or think I've read) in various places include the following:

- One `IndexWriter`, many `IndexReader`s
- When the index is updated, reset/ re-initialise the `IndexReader`s

Are there any other useful tips or resources I should read before starting?

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: I remember having problems accessing the Lucene files over UNC, but can't remember exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my tips (in no particular order):

- Choose the most appropriate locking mechanism.
- Use the SetRAMBufferSizeMB to reduce the disk I/O overhead when writing the index.
- Don't over use the SetMaxBufferedDocs property.
- Use the Search hits (TopDocs and ScoreDoc[]) object to retrieve the index search results.
- Index writing is an expensive operation, so use it sparingly.
- Know the data that you will be indexing as some data types (I.E., dates) can be difficult to search on if they are not stored consistently.

A few gotchas from one of my previous projects were:

- I had to use the BooleanQuery to do a traditional AND operation for searching multiple fields.
- There is no UPDATE functionality within Lucene so a document needs to be deleted and re-added.
- You can't sort / OrderBy on a tokenized field.

I would suggest looking at the source code for RavenDb as it is built on top of Lucene and uses a number of best practices.

Comment: Great tips, cheers. Locking seems a little random to me...do you know of anywhere that details the different types of locks and their usage?

Comment: You most definitely can update in lucene -- you just find the document, update the fields and re-add it to the index with the same key.

Comment: @Wyatt, the key is the documentid, and it's never changed within a segment. Are you thinking of IndexWriter.UpdateDocument which does a delete+add?

Answer (score 4):

RavenDb is definitely the easiest way to go here -- it really is lucene++.

In terms of how to use it, I'd recommend looking at the SubText blogging engine. Code is MIT licensed so you can just use it in your project and it has a very well designed index writer/reader.

In our apps, we tend to have one writer and a separate app with many readers. The locking strategy can be key here--especially make sure the readers don't try and lock the index. I'm blanking on the specific term we had to use to make this happen.

Comment: Great tips, especially around the locking. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that RavenDb is really something special